# AWS Athena - how to escape characters like ',' which are present in quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a table in Athena with three columns created with below template

```
Resources:
    TempDataMasterTable:
       Type: AWS::Glue::Table
       Properties:
         DatabaseName: "temp_db"
         CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
         TableInput:
           Name: "temp_table"
           Description: "Master table"
           TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
           Parameters: { "classification" : "csv", "compressionType" : "none", "typeOfData": "file" }
           StorageDescriptor:
             Location: s3://temp-location/temp-folder/
             InputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
             OutputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
             SerdeInfo:
               Parameters:
                 serialization.format: ','
                 field.delim: ','
                 SerializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
             Columns:
             - {"Name": "name", "Type": "string"}
             - {"Name": "address", "Type": "string"}
             - {"Name": "desig", "Type": "string"}
```

So basically columns are delimited by ',' but in my column 2 - address it is possible to have ',' for e.g one of the values in underlying csv has "housenumber,street,city" when we view the data in Athena the table is not being parsed correctly as street in the column 2 is being rendered as third column because of ',' being the delimiter.

Is there a way to escape the ',' which are given in quotes ?

Comment: can you replace org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe with org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde and try querying it again?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy - Thanks , this resolved the issue

Comment: I have posted the answer. Please accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `serde org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe` with `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde`. `LazySimpleSerDe` cannot well when there are commas present in side a column where as `OpenCSVSerde` can.